# How do variables work in PL/pgSQL functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to plpgsql functions.

Can anyone explain how this works?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(
    IN a TEXT,
    IN b  TEXT
        )
        RETURNS void AS $func$
        DECLARE
          cnt INT2;
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            COUNT(*)
          INTO STRICT
            cnt
          FROM
            pg_catalog.pg_class
          WHERE 1 = 1
            AND a = $1
            AND b = $2;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', cnt;
        END; $func$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# SELECT test1('1', '2');
NOTICE:  311
 test1
-------

(1 row)
```

Why does it even work? We don't have a and b attributes in pg_class? Why does NOTICE return the result of `select * from pg_class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are doing this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_class
WHERE 1 = 1
AND '1' = '1'
AND '2' = '2';

count 
-------
   554
```

and that is true so you get the same as doing this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_class
;

count 
-------
   554
```

If you want it to fail, take the ambiguity out of it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test1(a text, b text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
        DECLARE
          cnt INT2;
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            COUNT(*)
          INTO STRICT
            cnt
          FROM
            pg_catalog.pg_class
          WHERE 1 = 1
            AND pg_catalog.pg_class.a = $1
            AND pg_catalog.pg_class.b = $2;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', cnt;
        END; $function$
;

select test1('1', '2');
ERROR:  column pg_class.a does not exist
LINE 6:             AND pg_catalog.pg_class.a = $1
                        ^
QUERY:  SELECT
            COUNT(*)
                                                FROM
            pg_catalog.pg_class
          WHERE 1 = 1
            AND pg_catalog.pg_class.a = $1
            AND pg_catalog.pg_class.b = $2
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test1(text,text) line 5 at SQL statement
```

For more information see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST

"Since the names of variables are syntactically no different from the names of table columns, there can be ambiguity in statements that also refer to tables: is a given name meant to refer to a table column, or a variable? Let's change the previous example to

INSERT INTO dest (col) SELECT foo + bar FROM src;

Here, dest and src must be table names, and col must be a column of dest, but foo and bar might reasonably be either variables of the function or columns of src.

By default, PL/pgSQL will report an error if a name in a SQL statement could refer to either a variable or a table column. You can fix such a problem by renaming the variable or column, or by qualifying the ambiguous reference, or by telling PL/pgSQL which interpretation to prefer.

The simplest solution is to rename the variable or column. A common coding rule is to use a different naming convention for PL/pgSQL variables than you use for column names. For example, if you consistently name function variables v_something while none of your column names start with v_, no conflicts will occur.

Alternatively you can qualify ambiguous references to make them clear. In the above example, src.foo would be an unambiguous reference to the table column. To create an unambiguous reference to a variable, declare it in a labeled block and use the block's label (see Section 42.2). For example, ..."